# How do I scroll a WebView to a specific point on Android

Tags: android, webview, scroll

I have a WebView and I would like my app to find a mark on the text(I'm using the symbol ► in the html).I have lots of html files each with almost 10 of these markings.

I have done it pretty easily with TextView doing this:

```
    int offset=texto.indexOf("SPECIFIC MARKING ON TEXT");   
    final int line = textview.getLayout().getLineForOffset(offset); 
    final int y = textview.getLayout().getLineTop(line); // e.g. I want to scroll to line
    final ScrollView s = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01); 
    s.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            s.smoothScrollTo(0, y);
        }
    });
```

But how do I accomplish that on Webview ?
The reason I use Webview is due to better text formatting.

Comment: If it's really just formatted text you want, you can get HTML formatting in a TextView by using [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) to generate a Spanned, which can be added to a TextView.

Comment: I already tried that , but i guess it can't read the formatting i am using:Bold , underlined text , yellow background (highlighted) text and itallic .I'm pasting from word to a HTML editor and pasting the code to try that,does not give good results.Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it's even simpler with a WebView. You can use the [findAll method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#findAll%28java.lang.String%29) for the first occurrence, then [findNext(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#findNext%28boolean%29) for the following markers. The view will automatically scroll to the requested text.

Comment: hi, it is good solution to automatic scroll. But it scroll to the requested text at the bottom of the device. i want to scroll till the requested text top of the screen. any solution for this?

Comment: use this, then offset the scroll position by the view's height, minus the approximate text height. I would guess.